# Selenium-Python - How to reduce time for NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have a test case where I need to check that on clicking an element, a popup is NOT displayed. This code works fine, but it takes too long, 60 seconds for NoSuchElementException, print the PASS condition and move to next test case. How can I reduce the wait time in this case?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
".//*[@id='assetIdDIV']/div/myaots-input/div/div/div[1]/span/i[2]"
).click()

try:
    DUP_popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    ".//*[@id='DuplicateTicketsPopup']/div/div/div/div[1]/span[2]/img"
    )

    if (DUP_popup):
        print ("Duplicate tkts popup is displayed - Fail")

except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("Duplicate popup not displayed - PASS")
```

Comment: "Use this tag if your problem is caused by or primarily involves a NoSuchElementException in Java." How is this java?

Comment: This is not Java. This is Selenium with Python

Answer (score 1):

You can use explicit wait.

> WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500
>   milliseconds until it returns successfully within timeout, 
>   otherwise throw TimeoutException

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
  DUP_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPath, 
      "//*[@id='DuplicateTicketsPopup']/div/div/div/div[1]/span[2]/img"))
  )

  # This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException 
  # unless it finds the element to return within 10 seconds.

  if (DUP_popup):
    print ("Duplicate tkts popup is displayed - Fail")

except TimeoutException:
  print ("Duplicate popup not displayed - PASS")
```

More detail about explicit wait and implicit wait can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to why it would take as long as 60 seconds to raise *NoSuchElementException* and print the *pass* condition but you can configure the wait period through a waiter inducing *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='assetIdDIV']/div/myaots-input/div/div/div[1]/span/i[2]").click()
if(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='DuplicateTicketsPopup']/div/div/div/div[1]/span[2]/img"))))!= 0):
    print ("Duplicate tkts popup is displayed - Fail")
else:
    print ("Duplicate popup not displayed - PASS")
```

**Note** : Incase your program includes _implicitly_wait()_ you need to remove the instances of _implicitly_wait()_ as the documentation clearly mentions `Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`

Answer (score 0):

Check your driver instance's implicit wait value. If implicit value is set to 60secs, then it'll wait till 60secs to throw any selenium related exceptions.